# ImgCached in IONIC - How to cached img in Inline HTML

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

i use ionic to build cross-platform app.
In out program we need load some post from server like: promotion/ news.
To achieve it, i use ng-bind-html:

```
 <div ng-bind-html="inlineHtml|hrefToJS" style="padding:0px 10px 0px 10px">
```

I want to cached image in those post to client, that way my app can work offline have native mode, and smoothly.

i use: https://github.com/chrisben/imgcache.js/ to cached image
each time want to cached something , i just need add directives "img-cache" to img or div like this:

```
 <div class= "ProductImage" img-cache ic-bg="{{$root.config.imgUrl+image}}">
 </div>
```

But with inline html ( ng-bind-html above), i **can** replace all tag `<img src = "" >` in post to `<img img-cache src = "">` but cached not happen, maybe directives img-cache not called.

I try to use $sce to set trust JS and html , but still can not solve problem.

Can you help me solve this case.

Many thanks!.